# Laravel Validation Rule

Tags: laravel, validation

I have category table
Its has del_status

when delete category delstatus will change 1

now question is
when update category ,
I want to validate except del_status 0

because category is unique

eg  below is pseudo code :)

```
Rule::except(function ($query){
    return $query->where('del_status','1');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use The softDelete traits in your model. it will spare you a lot of trouble and will work as you want it to.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#soft-deleting

it will use a field in the DB table name `deleted_at`

Comment: Thanks you sir Can i customize the rule like my question .please answer me if you have any idea

Comment: you wont have to. a category with deleted_at different from null will not be considered just as if it was "deleted"